# Microblink: getting values after scanning

Tags: ios, microblink

I've set up the Microblink card reader to read only one side, and not give the user the ability to edit the scan results:

```
func didTapScan() {
        /** Create BlinkCard recognizer */
        blinkCardRecognizer = MBCBlinkCardRecognizer()
        blinkCardRecognizer?.extractCvv = false
        blinkCardRecognizer?.extractIban = false
        blinkCardRecognizer?.extractExpiryDate = false
        
        /** Create BlinkCard settings */
        let settings : MBCBlinkCardOverlaySettings = MBCBlinkCardOverlaySettings()
        settings.enableEditScreen = false
        
        /** Crate recognizer collection */
        let recognizerList = [blinkCardRecognizer!]
        let recognizerCollection : MBCRecognizerCollection = MBCRecognizerCollection(recognizers: recognizerList)
        
        /** Create your overlay view controller */
        let blinkCardOverlayViewController = MBCBlinkCardOverlayViewController(settings: settings, recognizerCollection: recognizerCollection, delegate: self)
        
        /** Create recognizer view controller with wanted overlay view controller */
        // NOTE that I put a bang on the end of this - not good
        let recognizerRunneViewController : UIViewController = MBCViewControllerFactory.recognizerRunnerViewController(withOverlayViewController: blinkCardOverlayViewController)!
        
        /** Present the recognizer runner view controller. You can use other presentation methods as well (instead of presentViewController) */
        self.present(recognizerRunneViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

After scanning, I check in the delegate callback for a valid state, and then I try to retrieve the values from the `cardRecognizer`, but I'm getting nothing but crashes:

```
func blinkCardOverlayViewControllerDidFinishScanning(_ blinkCardOverlayViewController: MBCBlinkCardOverlayViewController, state: MBCRecognizerResultState) {
        // this is done on background thread
        // check for valid state
        if state == .valid {
            
            CRASHES HERE
            guard let result = blinkCardRecognizer?.combinedResult else {
                return
            }
            // CRASHES HERE
            print (result)
            
            // first, pause scanning until we process all the results
            blinkCardOverlayViewController.recognizerRunnerViewController?.pauseScanning()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                print(self.blinkCardRecognizer)
                // self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done everything correctly regarding the first block of code.

Regarding the second part (in the `blinkCardOverlayViewControllerDidFinishScanning` method), the `.combinedResult` is the parent of the `result` object, so you can use the `blinkCardRecognizer.result` instead.

Also, there seems to be an issue with the recognizer's description method (`blinkCardRecognizer.result`), so you would need to specify which information you want to extract.

An example code would be:

```
extension ViewController: MBCBlinkCardOverlayViewControllerDelegate {
    func blinkCardOverlayViewControllerDidFinishScanning(_ blinkCardOverlayViewController: MBCBlinkCardOverlayViewController, state: MBCRecognizerResultState) {
        /** This is done on background thread */
        
        if state == .valid {

            guard let result = blinkCardRecognizer?.result else {
                  return
              }
            blinkCardOverlayViewController.recognizerRunnerViewController?.pauseScanning()

              DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                print(result.cardNumber)
              })
          }
      }
```